# Better Management of Binary Target of Exec Plugin

Tags: maven

Our build uses the exec plugin to execute a external binary.  The way we do this currently is that each developer must install the binary on their machine, and then configure the plugin with the path to the executable.  It seems to me that their must be some way to manage that binary itself as a dependency of the build.  I'm a bit new to maven so I don't immediately see how to best do this.  I'm thinking that the build should grab the binary on it's own, and execute it.  This would be a much more "portable" build than expecting developers to install the binary themselves.  So, what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just put the binary somewhere into the source code. Regarding the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html), the exec:exec looks for path "relative to the root of the project".